# Derivation of Digamma function

Tags: integration, gamma-function, digamma-function

In the paper by Kraskov et al (2004) there is a rather large jump in calculations. I am wondering if someone could fill out the gap for the equation below (equation 17 in the paper):

$$
k\binom{N-1}{k}\int_0^1 p^{k-1} (1-p)^{N-k-1} \ln(p) dp = \psi(k) - \psi(N)
$$

where $\psi(x)$ is the dimgamma function.

Reference:
Kraskov, A., Stögbauer, H., & Grassberger, P. (2004). Estimating mutual information. Physical review E, 69(6), 066138.

Comment: Note that $$
\frac{d}{{dk}}\int_0^1 {p^{k - 1} (1 - p)^{N - k - 1} dp}  + \frac{d}{{dN}}\int_0^1 {p^{k - 1} (1 - p)^{N - k - 1} dp}  = \int_0^1 {p^{k - 1} (1 - p)^{N - k - 1} \ln (p)dp} .
$$ Now compute the left-hand side by http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E1 and the fact that $
\Gamma '(x) = \Gamma (x)\psi (x)$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 p^{k-1} (1-p)^{N-k-1} \ln(p) dp =& \int_0^1 p^{k-1} (1-p)^{N-k-1} \left(\lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{d}{dt} p^t\right)dp \\
=& \lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1 p^{k+t-1} (1-p)^{N-k-1} dp \\
=&  \lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{d}{dt} B(k+t,N-k)\\
=& \lim_{t \to 0+} \left[\psi(k+t)-\psi(n+t)\right]B(k+t,N-k)\\
=& \left[\psi(k)-\psi(N)\right]B(k,N-k)\\
=& \left[\psi(k)-\psi(N)\right]\frac{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(N-k)}{\Gamma(N)}\\
=& \left[\psi(k)-\psi(N)\right]\frac{(k-1)!(N-k-1)!}{(N-1)!}\\
=& \left[\psi(k)-\psi(N)\right]\frac{k!(n-k-1)!}{k(N-1)!}\\
=& \left[\psi(k)-\psi(N)\right]\frac{1}{k\binom{N-1}{k}}
\end{align*}

$$ \boxed{ k\binom{N-1}{k}\int_0^1 p^{k-1} (1-p)^{N-k-1} \ln(p) dp = \psi(k)-\psi(N)} $$